# integrate $\int\frac{\sin x}{1+\sin^{2}x}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

> $$\int\frac{\sin x}{1+\sin^{2}x}\mathrm {dx}$$

$$\int\frac{\sin x}{1+\sin^{2}x}\mathrm {dx}=\int\frac{\sin x}{2-\cos^{2}x}\mathrm {dx}$$

$u=\cos x$

$du=-\sin x dx$

$$-\int\frac{\mathrm {du}}{2-u^{2}}$$

How could I continue?

Comment: ........$dudx$??

Comment: @Nehorai sorry edited

Comment: $$\frac1{2 -u^2} = \frac1{2\sqrt{2}} \left(\frac1{\sqrt{2} +u} + \frac1{\sqrt{2}-u}\right)$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Write $$\frac{-1}{2-u^2}=\frac{-1}{(\sqrt{2}+u)(\sqrt{2}-u)}=\frac{-1}{2\sqrt{2}}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}+u}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}-u}\right)$$

Answer (score 2):

$$-\int\frac{du}{2-u^{2}}\\
=-\frac 1 2 \int\frac{du}{1-u^2/2}$$

Set $t=u/\sqrt 2$ and $dt=\frac{du}{\sqrt 2}$

$$=-\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\int \frac {1}{1-t^2}dt\\
=-\frac{\arctan\text{h}(t)}{\sqrt 2}+C\\
=-\frac{\arctan\text{h}(u/\sqrt 2)}{\sqrt 2}+C$$

Comment: The integral does not give arctan(t).

Comment: I think you want $\text{arctanh}(t)$ instead of $\arctan(t)$.

Answer (score 2):

Notice, factorize & use partial fractions as follows  $$-\int \frac{du}{2-u^2}=-\int \frac{du}{(\sqrt2-u)(\sqrt2+u)}$$
$$=-\frac{1}{2\sqrt 2}\int \left(\frac{1}{\sqrt 2-u}+\frac{1}{\sqrt 2+u}\right)\ du$$
$$=-\frac{1}{2\sqrt 2} \left(-\ln|\sqrt 2-u|+\ln|\sqrt2+u|\right)+C$$
$$=-\frac{1}{2\sqrt 2}\ln\left|\frac{\sqrt 2+u}{\sqrt 2-u}\right|+C$$
$$=\frac{1}{2\sqrt 2}\ln\left|\frac{\sqrt 2-u}{\sqrt 2+u}\right|+C$$
$$=\color{red}{\frac{1}{2\sqrt 2}\ln\left|\frac{\sqrt 2-\cos x}{\sqrt 2+\cos x}\right|+C}$$

Comment: Just for the check I derive http://goo.gl/Oj8vy0